Query elements by attribute of Foreignkey Relation and also Query Foreign attributes most efficient
There are three models
Product: Having an id, a name
Storage: Having an id, a name, a color and a branch
ProductStorage: Maps each Product to a Storage and has some extra attributes.
I want to list all ProductStorages with a specific Storage.branch value grouped by the Storage, displaying storage name and color too.
Is it possible to do this in one query? I am new to Django and I am unsure how to do this in the most efficient way.
I know that I could query all ProductStorages and filter by branch. Then sort them maybe afterwards by their storages and query the storage-attributes in a second query. But I guess this won't be the best way to do it.
Example (All ProductStorages grouped by Storages):
"Storage.Name1, Storage.Color1":
ProductStorage.Name1, ProductStorage.attr1, ...
ProdcutStorage.Name2, ProductStorage.attr2, ...
ProductStorage.Name3, ProductStorage.attr3, ...
...

"Storage.Name2, Storage.Color2":
ProductStorage.Name1, ProductStorage.attr1, ...
ProdcutStorage.Name2, ProductStorage.attr2, ...
ProductStorage.Name3, ProductStorage.attr3, ...
...


It'd be easier if you give an example of the expected result

@pleasedontbelong I tried to outline the structure I want to display. Please see my edit.

Just query with the related Storage and ProductStorages:
from django.db.models import Prefetch

products = Product.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'productstorage_set', ProductStorage.objects.select_related('storage')
    )
)
then we can group the items by the corresponding name and color:
from collections import defaultdict

for product in products:
    product.items = defaultdict(list)
    for item in product.productstorage_set.all():
        product.items[item.storage.name, item.storage.color].append(item)
and pass products to the template:
{% for product in products %}
    <h1>{{ product.name }}</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for key, val in product.items %}
        <li><b>{{ key.0 }} - {{ key.1 }}</b>
        {% for item in val %}
            <li>{{ item.name }} - {{ item.extra_attr }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}

Thanks a lot. I used this, and just swapped it to query by storage and not product. Then I did not even have to group it.

I'd invert the query: instead of requesting ProductStorage you could query Storage and use prefetch_related to get the related products, also I'd define the relation between Storage and Product using "through"
Then your query would be something like:
Storage.objects.all().prefetch_related("products")

Or with a .filter(branch=..). if you want to filter a branch
for example:
storages = Storage.objects.filter(branch__in=("foo", "bar")).prefetch_related("products")
for storage in storages:
    print(storage.name)
     # there won't be a query because prefetch_related already did it
    for product in storage.products: 
         print(product.name)


Thanks for the through-hint! But this will only give me a List of Storage objects? How can I access the according Products in the end?

the prefetch_related will do that for you, I'll update my answer

Hmmm somehow it does not work for me. If I print storage.products I get app.Product.None. And I can't iterate over storage.products. Even though I added this to the Storage Model: products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through="ProductStorage")

ahh with for product in storage.products.all() it works.

But I get many duplicate Storages doing it like this. Do I need to use groupBy from sql somehow? I get a storage there for each StorageProduct.

And also how do I access ProductStorage attributes like in my Example? Don't I only have products and storages now?

ah yes.. i forgot the .all(). For the GROUP BY It's not clear what you're trying to do, you say you want to "group by storage" but that's not clear enough. On your example you have 2 storages and for each storage you display every product on that storage: that's not a "group by". Maybe you could create another question where you give the exact sql query and we can tell you how to do that using django's orm

No, in my Example I do not display every product on that storage. I display the ProductStorage. This is another table, with extra attributes. Also with group by I mean the problem that with your code, I get each storage multiple times. I don't know why. But if a storage has 10 products. I get this storage 10 times in your request. Thank you so much for your help!

Ohh the multiple items come from me also filtering for products__isnull=False. I don't understand why this happens though. .filter(branch=current_branch, products__isnull=False)
